# Why the searcher is not returning results?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have created an index using solr. I am trying to execute the following code, but I get zero results in the count.

```
DirectoryReader dr = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir).toPath()));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher( dr );

System.out.println(dr.maxDoc()); // Shows 2000000
Query query = new FieldValueQuery("table");
CollectionStatistics stats = searcher.collectionStatistics("table");
System.out.println(stats.docCount()); // Shows 2000000

System.out.println(searcher.count(query)); //Shows 0, should be 2000000
```

The definition of the table filed in the schema.xml is:

```
<field name="table" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

The code for adding document to the index is:

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("table", "job", 1.0f);
solrclient.add(doc);
solrclient.commit();
```

Any idea, why this could be happening? Why the search with the FieldValueQuery is not returning the correct result?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you show how are you indexing docs ? what is your schema.xml looks ike?

Comment: I have edited the question, so you have now all the details

Comment: According to https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldValueQuery.html it'll use the LeafReader.getDocsWithField() method, which depends on docvalues. Not sure if they're enabled by default by your current schema version?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test the code provider, I tried to run it against my existing index and replace the name of the field with different typologies of fields in my index.
I have an index with the following schema.xml:

```
<field name="tag" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" />
<field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

When I tried your code in the following way:

```
DirectoryReader dr = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(directory.toPath()));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher( dr );
    Query query = new FieldValueQuery("author");
    System.out.println(searcher.count(query));
```

and the result was 0 documents.
Then I tried with the other fields in my schema (whose subset I copied above), replacing them in the FieldValueQuery like:

```
Query query = new FieldValueQuery("tag");
```

and the correct count (47000 for me) showed up.

> That means that searcher.count **depends on DocValues**, so changing
>   the schema in the following way will solve your problem:

```
<field name="table" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
```

If you don't want or you can't change your schema, then you could always rely on the old way to count documents like:

```
searcher.search(query,collector);
int count = collector.getTotalHits();
```